# How to stop Sitecore Rich Text Field pre-pending the item URL to hand written URL in the field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have content in a Rich Text Field where the HTML view of the content looks like this

```
<li>
  <div class="hotel">
    <div class="title">Day 0 HILTON LONDON METROPOLE</div>
    <div class="detail">225 EDGWARE ROAD LONDON W2 1JU<br/>
      44 207 4024141<br/>
      <a href="www.hiltonlondonmet.com/">www.hiltonlondonmet.com/</a><br/>
    </div>
 </div>
</li>
```

The html source on the website comes out like this

```
<div class="hotel">
  <div class="title">Day 0 HILTON LONDON METROPOLE</div>
  <div class="detail">225 EDGWARE ROAD LONDON W2 1JU
  <br />44 207 4024141
  <br />
  <a href="www.hiltonlondonmet.com/">www.hiltonlondonmet.com/</a>
  <br /></div>
</div>
```

But when I click on the link (or copy the link) it comes out like this

http://www.myfakesite.com.au/full/path/to/the/item/containing/the/link/www.hiltonlondonmet.com/

Which then gives a page not found error if clicked.

The content of this field is created programmatically, do I need to use the LinkManager to create the link?

I tried creating a link via the Editor button and the source comes out like a plain link but it is handled differently when clicked on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is append "http://" to the href attribute on the link to tell the browser the URL is not located on your domain.

```
<a href="http://www.hiltonlondonmet.com">www.hiltonlondonmet.com</a>
```

Comment: Yep, its standard browser behaviour, its not specific to Sitecore.

Comment: Blah. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.